# Emacs, which to use?

Tags: package-management, emacs

There seem to be the following versions: emacs23, emacs23-nox, e3, emacs23-lucid, and jove, as choices to download. Where can I find out what the differences are?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between emacs and emacs-lucid packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386177/difference-between-emacs-and-emacs-lucid-packages)

Answer (score 38):

The short answer is that you almost certainly want `emacs23`: it's the full version of Emacs 23 with graphical support.

`emacs23-nox` is the same, but without any graphical support.  If you're installing Emacs onto a server or other environment that lacks an X window system, you should fetch this version instead.  (Note that `emacs23` works just fine on the terminal, so the *only* reason to prefer `emacs23-nox` to `emacs23` is if you don't want to drag in the dependencies.)

`e3` and `jove` are not Emacs; they're lightweight editors that have Emacs modes to them.

`emacs23-lucid` is XEmacs, which used to be called "Lucid Emacs".

Comment: 2014 here. should it be emacs24 now?

Comment: The `-lucid` variant is useful if you want X without a graphical desktop, e.g. over ssh.

Comment: ^ The version without graphical support is the `-nox` variant.

Comment: There is no emacs24-nox yet. emacs23-nox is still the latest for ubuntu as of Jul 2014.

Comment: emacs24-nox is available as of this writing (Sept 2014).

Comment: In my environment, a relatively clean Debian 8.1, apt-get told me that  emacs24nox would use ~ 104 MB of additional disk space vs 284 MB for emacs24. On my server anyway, that is significant.The size of the install was keeping me from installing the package. I didn't know there was a lighter option.  I'm most grateful for the question and the answers here.

Comment: `e3` is not similar to Emacs... for example, to exit, you don't use `^x ^c`, you use `^k ^q` instead.  Jove is closer to Emacs, at least for most of the keystrokes, such as `^a`, `^e`, `^p`, `^n`, `^x ^c`.  In fact, at UC Berkeley, some teachers and students liked to use Jove instead of Emacs (at least in the old days, not sure about now).

Comment: actually, `e3` is strange... if you start it by typing `e3`, it behaves one way, but if you start it by typing `emacs`, then it behaves more like emacs

Comment: @SabreWolfy, I did not express that well. I use emacs-lucid if I want to install emacs on a server and use it with X forwarded over ssh.

Comment: You should note that you may want the full emacs (e.g. emacs24) even on a system without a graphical console if you are going to remotely log in from another computer that is running an X server.  In general, I only recommend the -nox variation if your storage is very limited (e.g. an embedded environment)

Comment: I am having `E: Package 'emacs23-nox' has no installation candidate` inside a docker image @Benjamin Pollack